# How can I cut a Line drawn on canvas into two parts

Tags: c#, wpf, line

Say I drew a Line on a Canvas. I need simply cut/split the Line to have two lines.

```
Line line = new Line();
SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
brush.Color = colorPicker2.SelectedColor;
line.Stroke = brush;
line.StrokeThickness = SliderThickness.Value;
line.X1 = currentPoint.X;
line.Y1 = currentPoint.Y;
line.X2 = e.GetPosition(DrawPanel).X;
line.Y2 = e.GetPosition(DrawPanel).Y;
currentPoint = e.GetPosition(DrawPanel);
DrawPanel.Children.Add(line);
```

I'm sorry that I wasn't been specific. The user will click on a point of the line and the line will be cut at that point into two pieces. Then the user will drag or move each part of the line.

Comment: how u wanna cut it ? even if you cut it in middle you wont see any difference until the start point of one is different on end point of other..

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. Can you explain in more detail what you want to do, or simply draw it in paint?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var middleX = (line.X1 + line.X2) / 2;
var middleY = (line.Y1 + line.Y2) / 2;

Line line1 = new Line();
line1.X1 = line.X1;
line1.Y1 = line.Y1;
line1.X2 = middleX;
line1.Y2 = middleY;

Line line2 = new Line();
line2.X1 = middleX;
line2.Y1 = middleY;
line2.X2 = line.X2;
line2.Y2 = line.Y2;
```

Comment: have u tried this ? does this look 2 different lines on ui ? I think op is not clear what he is looking for right now ..

Comment: You can change location of one of the lines and it will be look like 2 different lines. I think it's not purpose of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            Line line = new Line();
            SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush();
            brush.Color = colorPicker2.SelectedColor;
            line.Stroke = brush;
            line.StrokeThickness = SliderThickness.Value;
            line.X1 = currentPoint.X;
            line.Y1 = currentPoint.Y;
            line.X2 = e.GetPosition(DrawPanel).X;
            line.Y2 = e.GetPosition(DrawPanel).Y;
            currentPoint = e.GetPosition(DrawPanel);
            DrawPanel.Children.Add(line);

            Point middlePoint = ((line.X1 + line.X2) / 2, (line.Y1 + line.Y2) / 2)

            Line newFirst = new Line();
            newFirst.X1 = line.X1;
            newFirst.Y1 = line.Y1;
            newFirst.X2 = middlePoint.X;
            newFirst.Y2 = middlePoint.Y;
            newFirst.Stroke = brush;
            newFirst.StrokeThickness = SliderThickness.Value;

            Line newSecond = new Line();
            newSecond.X1 = middlePoint.X;
            newSecond.Y1 = middlePoint.Y;
            newSecond.X2 = line.X2;
            newSecond.Y2 = line.Y2;
            newSecond.Stroke = brush;
            newSecond.StrokeThickness = SliderThickness.Value;

            DrawPanel.Children.Remove(line);
            DrawPanel.Children.Add(newFirst);
            DrawPanel.Children.Add(newSecond);
```

Comment: how is this different from ans posted ?

Comment: 1. When i posted the answer i didn't see yours, the page wasnt refreshed :)
2. the other answer doesn't handle the UI. it creates two logical lines according the points given, but it doesn't render it on canvas as two different lines.
with my answer if youll change for example the color of "newFirst", youll see a line that is cut to half by color

Comment: Idea is not to make such mistakes and let all the users go through two answers which are same. usually the pages change dynamically so that we can avoid this mistake.. for your 2nd point please make sure that you do not spoon feed OP, we must always initiate the thinking process rather than giving all pre cooked...  and just so that you know I did not post the answer

Comment: Ok. new to stackoverflow. -_-

Comment: I'm sorry that I wasn't been specific. The user will click on a point of the line and the line will be cut at that point. Then the user will drag or move each part of the line.